# ObjectDisposedException in web service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, exception

I am doing a web service as a project and I have a problem I just cant seem to figure out. I think its something about lazy loading and my using statement.

Heres my code:

```
public List<MediumRole> MediumGetParticipants(int mediumId, int itemsPrPage, int page)
{
    Medium medium = MediaHelper.GetMedium(mediumId);

    // Check if media not is null
    if (medium == null) return null;

    return medium.MediumRoles.Page(page, itemsPrPage).ToList();
}
```

I get an exception saying

> System.ObjectDisposedException: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection. 
>   Anybody?

Comment: Where is your using statement? You need to add more code (GetMedium, etc.) to get an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood `Medium` class has  lazy load proxy reference to collection of `MediumRoles`.

Exception caused because `MediaHelper.GetMedium(mediumId)` method disposes database context to which `Medium` is refered.

To solve this problem you can do something like this:

```
public static List<MediumRole> MediumGetParticipants(int mediumId, int itemsPrPage, int page)
    {
        Medium medium = MediaHelper.GetMedium(mediumId);
        // Check if media not is null
        if (medium == null) return null;
        using (var context = new DbContext())
        {
          context.Attach(medium);
          return medium.MediumRoles.Page(page, itemsPrPage).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I' guessing that you use Entity Framework, have lazy loading enabled (that's the default), and dispose the EF's `ObjectContext` in the `GetMedium` method. When you access the `MediumRoles` property, EF wants to lazy load the collection, but it cannot, since the `ObjectContext` is already disposed. To solve the problem, you can change your code so that the context is disposed after the call to `ToList`, or that `MediumRoles` collection is eagerly loaded in the `GetMedium` method.